# Navigation is not working with Rows in ListView

Tags: react-native

I have a list of elements contains in a ListView component. My elements are built with data in a .json.

My screen with the list is built like this :

**ListBillScreen.js**

```
    <View style ={styles.header}>
      <Text style = {styles.textHeader}> Vos Factures </Text>
    </View>

  <ListView
    style={styles.listView}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />}
    renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
  />

  <View style = {styles.footer}>
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.goAdd.bind(this)}>
       <Image style={ styles.image } source={require('../Images/add_blue.png')}/>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
  <AndroidBackButton
    onPress={this.popIfExists.bind(this)}
  />

</ScrollView>
);
```

As you can see, i have in render row the line

```
renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />}
```

Row references

**Row.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Alert, TouchableHighlight, Navigator} from 'react-native';

import styles from './Styles/RowStyles'

const Row = (props) => (
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Alert.alert("Redirection " + 
props.name)}>
 <View style={styles.container}>
  <Image source={{ uri: props.picture}} style={styles.photo} />
  <Text style={styles.text}>
   {`${props.name} / ${props.price} euros`}
  </Text>
 </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
);

export default Row;
```

Instead of the

```
{() => Alert.alert("Redirection " + props.name)}>
```

I would like to make a redirection with the function :

```
goAdd(){
  this.props.navigator.push({ screen: 'BillScreen' });
}
```

But if do that, I have an error that told me this.props.navigator is not working in this case. But in others classes i'm doing that and everything is all right.

Is someone have a solution please? Thanks for all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass `navigator` as props down to the Row.js

```
  <ListView
    style={styles.listView}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} navigator={this.props.navigator}/>}
    renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks it was that ! Thanks again =D